# how to get the date only in iOS not time

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

I want to get the only date in iOS and not time 
my code is

```
extension Date{
   var DateInDate: Date{
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy-MM-dd")
      formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")
      let dateInString = formatter.string(from: self)
      return formatter.date(from: dateInString)!
   }
}
```

if I am doing by the above format I am getting the answer as "Apr 3, 2019 at 12: 00 AM"

my other code is

```
extension Date{
   var DateInDate: String{
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateStyle = .short
      formatter.timeStyle = .none
      formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy-MM-dd")
      formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")
      let dateInString = formatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

but in this way, I am getting in string format and not a Date format

I want the answer in date format

Comment: A `Date` object represents a specific point in time. So you cannot just discard the hour/minute/second part of it. What is it that you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Time is a part of date object you can not remove it but you can make it `00:00` if needed, but before doing that you should verify that you're doing the thing you actually want to do.

Comment: lets say today is april 3rd 2019 based on my location i want just that only not the time like april 3rd 2019 16:00:43 as my app is storing data of particular day not time

Comment: I think you don't need to return a `Date` instead return a `String` from `formatter.string(from: self)`.

Comment: in the first code i am returning the date only it still has time in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments a `Date` instance without the time portion is impossible.

In terms of `Date` a timeless date is midnight, the *start of the day*.

There is an convenience API in `Calendar`:

```
let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
```

Comment: I am still getting the time as 12:00 AM in the answer

Comment: Yes of course because the time is `00:00:00` (mostly) and `print`ing a date prints a generic description string which includes the time.

Comment: I really want to upvote not because it provided the answer I wanted but decreases the 5 line of code to just 1

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents) instead. Date would always have the time.

Comment: Explain your answer with example how to get only Date from datecomponents otherwise this answer is low quality and containing link only and is to be a comment. Moreover please go though  this [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: `let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let comps = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day],
                                                from: Date())`

You can`t get Date object and should work only with this.

Comment: Update your answer instead of posting comments to it by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55491266/edit)

Comment: I am able to get only year month and day using Vlad_sh's answer but if I convert this back to date format (as my model has date type and not date component type) I am getting current time along with the year month and day

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 let date = Date()
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
 dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
 dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: it will return an string in my model i am using date not string